# How do get uninitialzed variable warning from Clang 2.9?

Tags: clang

I have this file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int i;
   printf("%d\n",i);
   return 0;
}
```

If I compile with gcc 4.6.1 on Mint 12:

```
CC -Wall -O test_gcc.c
test_gcc.c: In function ‘main’:
test_gcc.c:8:10: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Those same options with clang 2.9 do not give a warning.
The Clang online manual shows a -Weverything, but this version doesn't know about it

```
clang -Weverything test_gcc.c
warning: unknown warning option '-Weverything' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
```

also

```
clang -Wuninitialized test_gcc.c
```

does not give a warning

How would I get a warning for an uninitialized variable read in clang 2.9?

Answer (score 0):

Get a newer version of clang; 2.9 is over a year old.